# View changes in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

For example, I have website and it's external SQL database. I've added page on my site. How can I watch SQL queries of adding page? It'll be perfect if there is such ability in SSMS.

Comment: Try SQL Server Profiler, it comes with the SQL Server client tools

Comment: Why downvote?  The OP has a question and is asking for our help.

Comment: a lot of thanks! yes, it was stupid question, but I haven't rich knowledges in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful technique I use which requires to have access to the server's terminal (e.g. via SSH) is the [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command combined with [mysql --execute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute). E.g.

```
$ watch -n .5 "mysql -uusername -ppassword db_name -t \
  -e 'SELECT id, name FROM tbl1 WHERE 1 order by created_at DESC LIMIT 5'"
```

This will print a screen with result of the MySQL statement and update it twice in a second. Any changes made to `tbl1` can be observed on the terminal screen.

The `- t` command line option tells MySQL to tabulate the output so the column values are vertically aligned.

You can also add multiple statements within the `- e ''` command line option separated by `;` so you can observe two or more tables at once and see the output as ASCII formatted tables below each other.